# Formatting a date string - PHP

Tags: php, date, format, search-engine

I have a dynamically allocated date from a search engine api results set entered into a multidimensional array, `$search_results['Date']`

There are two types of Date Data returned, first engine returns, for three result tests:

1. Example 1: `2013-07-22T12:00:03Z`
2. Example 2: `2013-07-23T18:18:15Z`
3. Example 3: `2013-07-21T23:57:04Z`

And for the same items, different engine:

1. Example 1: `1374495037`
2. Example 2: `1374528579`
3. Example 3: `1374515617`

I was hoping somebody here may have had experience on formatting dates and may be able to help me out?

I would like the format returned to be:

`22nd July, 2013. 12.00pm`

However the time part is not strictly necessary, but it would be nice to have the date sorted properly.

It seems the second engine returns the date in a bizarre format, can anybody figure it out? I am from Europe, we do dates different to those of you in America!?

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to format these dates?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Have you made any research? What are the results of it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the example 1 date string into strtotime() and seeing if strtotime can already interpret it correctly?  My best guess for the first examples is that the T is hard coded in and that the Z is for Zulu / time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for first example, you can use first strtotime(), a function that converts datetime to UNIX timestamp like this:

```
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime('2013-07-23T18:18:15Z'));
echo $date.'<br/>'; //put here just for  testing
```

and for second example you already have string as UNIX timestamp, so you don't need strtotime()

```
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s','1374495037');
echo $date.'<br/>';//put here just  for testing
```

format that you would like to return would be:

```
date('jS F, Y. h.ia',$unix_timestamp);
```

for other options for date formats consult: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php