# How to put a dot in the key?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform a post using angular js. In Angular, you pass the data as an object. Because of the server, I need the keys in the object to conatin dots, like the first one here:

```
$scope.quiz= {
    entry.358412101: 'asdf',
    formkey: '1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI',
    draftResponse: '[]'
}
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Enclose the key in quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

Comment: I would love a comment on the downvote, maybe I can learn something!

Comment: @jon I kindly disagree, while the answer is the same, the question is different, because I didn't know ou were suppose to put quotes around the key I would have never found that question!

Comment: That's why you asked the question and other people who do know about the relationship vote that it's a dupe. The point is that answers already exist (and they are much better than what will be found here), so both you and future visitors are better served by a link to the dupe. It has nothing to do with you personally realizing the similarity.

Comment: oh, sorry, I thought you wanted to close it, my bad ;)

Comment: I do want to close it, and then it will look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820666/formatting-a-date-string-php). Closing != deleting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as Jon said:

```
$scope.quiz= {
    "entry.358412101": 'asdf',
    formkey: '1F9trPeu9DA4W0CjADN4a1fl3Jh682ZPF8remWB21RhI',
    draftResponse: '[]'
}
```